# Error 0xc000007b when trying to start \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi (Ubuntu) through Windows 8.1 Bootmanager on an UEFI System

Tags: windows-8.1, multi-boot, bootloader, uefi, grub2

Error 0xc000007b when trying to start \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi (Ubuntu) through Windows 8.1 Bootmanager on an UEFI System

#### EFI Entries

During Ubuntu Setup, Ubuntu automatically created an EFI start Entry called `ubuntu`. The entry works, if I use the *UEFI Bootloader* directly. My EFI Boot entries looks like this:

```
Entry #9
Name: ubuntu
BCD ID: {a738afa2-8136-11e3-824f-806e6f6e6963}
Device: \Device\HarddiskVolume3
Bootloader Path: \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi

Entry #18
Name: Windows 8.1
BCD ID: {current}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.efi
```

#### ***Use a device*** - Submenu

I want to start `ubuntu` through *Windows 8.1 Bootloader*. At the *Windows 8.1 Bootloader* screen you have the option to selecect ***Use a device*** in a submenu. In this submenu there are all existing *UEFI Bootloeader* listed. I can select `ubuntu` and after a reboot i can see correctly the *GRUB* screen.

#### Add Entry to *Windows 8.1 Bootloader*

Now I add the existing Entry from the ***Use a device*** to *primary Windows 8.1 Bootloader list*:

```
bcdedit /displayorder {a738afa2-8136-11e3-824f-806e6f6e6963} /addlast
```

bcdedit output:

```
c:\>bcdedit /enum

Windows-Start-Manager
---------------------
Bezeichner              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume3
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  de-DE
inherit                 {globalsettings}
integrityservices       Enable
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {dd3893a3-8112-11e3-a3ae-ef458f8a8f20}
displayorder            {current}
                        {dd3893a8-8112-11e3-a3ae-ef459f8a8f20}
                        {a738afa2-8136-11e3-824f-806e6f6e6963}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 5

Windows-Startladeprogramm
-------------------------
Bezeichner              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 8.1
locale                  de-DE
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {dd3893a5-8112-11e3-a3ae-ef458f8a8f20}
integrityservices       Enable
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {dd3893a3-8112-11e3-a3ae-ef458f8a8f20}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard

Firmwareanwendung (101fffff)
----------------------------
Bezeichner              {a738afa2-8136-11e3-824f-806e6f6e6963}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume3
path                    \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
description             ubuntu
```

If I then select `ubuntu` from the *primary Windows 8.1 Bootloader list* following Error occurs after a reboot (It is translated so the original English wording could be different) :

```
Error during start of Windows.

File: \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi

State: 0xc000007b

Info: The Application or the Operating System could not be loaded, because a required file is missing or it contains mistakes.
```

Note the Entry from ***Use a device*** still works. So what had happened? It should be the same entry?

#### Add Entry Manually

I also tried to add an entry manually:

```
bcdedit /create /d "Ubuntu Test" /application bootsector
bcdedit /set {UUID_generated_by_/create} device partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume3
bcdedit /set {UUID_generated_by_/create} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
bcdedit /displayorder {UUID_generated_by_/create} /addlast
```

But the same error occurs.

Comment: What filesystem is used on the partition `shimx64.efi` resides on?

Comment: It is a *EFI-System Partition*, 100MB in Size, created by Windows 8.1 and is formatted as **FAT32** as it should. [Tree of files if you need them](https://gist.github.com/raabf/8caa45b5ec9bcb8917bd)

Comment: From a previous answer using Mac: does the file "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi" actually exist in your Ubuntu install?

Comment: Yea does it. [See here for a list of files in the EFI- System partition](https://gist.github.com/raabf/8caa45b5ec9bcb8917bd). If not GRUB should not be working (with the other boot options). Or does you mean something else with "in your Ubuntu install"? Linux does also simply mount the *EFI-System Partition* in `/boot/efi`.

Answer (score 0):

Although I cannot verify it now due to lack of time, according to [this guide](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/EFI_Problembehebung#Mein-Ubuntu-ist-nicht-im-EFI-Menue), the correct entry type is `bootsector`, whereas the entry type in your configuration is somehow that of a firmware application. I suggest recreating the entry.

[image: asdf]

Comment: Thanks, well the {a738afa2-8136-11e3-824f-806e6f6e6963} works outside the *primary Windows 8.1 Bootloader list* and was created by the Ubuntu Setup, so it should be theoretically correct. that was my thought ...
Nonetheless I also found the guide you mentioned and so I also tried an *bootsector* entry. See **Add Entry Manually** Section in my question. But the *bootector* entry produces the exactly same error ...

Comment: @F.Raab Well, I was able to reproduce your issue. I guess there’s no solution, just use Grub as the primary boot manager.

Comment: Well then my TPM Module does not work, so that is also not a solution for my problem^^ ...

Comment: @F.Raab Wow, okay, didn’t see that one coming. Maybe you’ll have better luck with [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/). Other than that, I’m out of ideas, sorry. I’ll try one more time with Windows 7 though, just for fun.

Comment: Yea that's OK^^ maybe another one has an idea. *rEFInd* is maybe an workaround since it does not load the kernel, so it might work ... mhmm perhaps I try if I have time.